# Connecting to remote mysql server over the INTERNET (NOT LAN) using workbench

Tags: mysql, networking, ssh, mysql-workbench

I have MySQL Workbench installed at Home Computer and MySQL server installed at office Computer. I want to access office database from home.
I have tried to connect with Public IP Address too but It takes a while and shows an error message. I have tried SSH port forwarding also but it is not working!

Any other Solutions?

Comment: Do you have VPN at your Office ? If so, connect to VPN from home and try to access the data base with the IP address of the server.
Otherwise please check if you can do ssh to the office computer first.

Comment: You have to open the ports (for Mysql is 3306) in your office computer. You will have to open that port in your office router and redirect it to your computer

Comment: @N.s.PraveenE No, I don't have VPN at my office.

Comment: @nacho I'll try this one!

Comment: I feel VPN is better and secure than opening a port @nacho.

Comment: @N.s. Praveen E Yes, you are right, VPN it's the best option, but if he doesn't have one ....